# Get data from .json file without XML in MockServer

Tags: sapui5, mockserver

I'm new in SAPUI5 and on this way at all. I'm sorry if my question looks stupid.

I created a project and MockServer in this project.

Now I want to get data from "products.json" file and show it in my "localServer.html". But I don't have "metadata.xml" file.

Can I get the necessary data without creating "metadata.xml" and if it's possible can anybody give me some advice or show me how to do that.

[image: My project view]

Comment: you dont need a mockServer if you dont have metadata information. just create a file with your JSON data and consume the data in a JSON model https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/96804e3315ff440aa0a50fd290805116.html#loio96804e3315ff440aa0a50fd290805116

Comment: Thanks a lot for answer. 
I have data in product.json, but don't have .xml file wich create this data.
Is it possible to get the data from product.json without any metadata.xml?

Comment: 1.upload yout file to your project 2. use the oModel.loadData("products.json"); example from the URL . it will consume your file without .xml